# Parallel pipeline in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pipeline

I want to create a parallel pipeline in C#. I have declaered an Interface named IOperation:

```
public interface IOperation<Tin, Tout>
{
    BlockingCollection<Tout> BlockingCollection(IEnumerable<Tin> input);
}
```

Now i want to write a class, which executes multiple of these operations parallel.
I bagan with this:

```
public class Pipeline : IPipeline
{
    private List<IOperation<Object, Object>> operations = new List<IOperation<Object, Object>>();
    private List<BlockingCollection<Object>> buffers = new List<BlockingCollection<Object>>();
    public void Register(IOperation<Object, Object> operation)
    {
        operations.Add(operation);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {

    }
}
```

But i don't find any solution to save the operations and the buffers between the operations, because they all have different generic types. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "save"?

Comment: I want to have them in the two lists at the top of the Pipeline class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Parallel.ForEach from the TPL?
The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is a set of public types and APIs in .NET 4.

Comment: Can I make a foreach loop that waits for new inputs if nothing is in the list anymore?

Comment: I suppose so. Instead of using a List<T>, use a method returning a IEnumerable<T>. In that method if data is available then 'yield return' the data, otherwise wait for a synchronization signal (for instance a Monitor being Pulsed).

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear how your Pipeline is meant to work.  Why are you passing around BlockingCollections?  Why are you using generics but then putting `object` in as the type?

Consider instead having a Pipeline that you load with deleggates of type `Action` and then use the task parallel library to create Tasks that execute those actions in parallel.

```
public void Register(Action operation)
    {
        operations.Add(operation);
    }

public void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var action in operations)
          Task.StartNew(operation);
    }
```

But that's not really a 'pipeline', it's just a bundle of operations that execute in parallel.

A pipeline would more normally have pipeline steps with an input type and an output type.  You could handle this by creating something like `PipelineStep<T,U>` and you'd construct each pipeline step passing in a Func operation.  Internally, each pipeline step could consume an input IEnumerable and produce an output IEnumerable and it could do this using Task or more simply using a parallel foreach loop.

Alternatively you could perhaps use the TPL's `Task.ContinueWith` method to chain the Tasks together from input to output.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has something exactly like this -- [TPL Dataflow](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/) lets you define blocks in a pipeline, with fine-grained controls on how they are buffered and parallelized.

Unlike your solution, it uses a fully asynchronous push design. It does not use a `BlockingCollection` (a blocking pull design), and will be significantly faster for it if you have a deep pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx about parallel pipelines with BlockingCollection.

Basically each step should have an output queue of type BlockingCollection.  It takes in items from the previous step's output queue, and adds them to it's output once done processing.